# Zend Framework Module access

Tags: zend-framework

I have created a module called Admin and created a controller Admin through zend tool. and added follwoing code in the bootstrap

```
protected function _initAutoLoad ()
{
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->setControllerDirectory(array(
                            'default' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/default/controllers' ,
                            'Admin'   => APPLICATION_PATH . '/Admin/controllers'
                                  ));
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->suppressNotFoundWarnings(false);
}
```

But if I am accessing http://localhost/zf_hemr/Admin url I am getting "Not Found" error. if I am accessing "http://localhost/zf_hemr/public/Admin" url I am getting following error:

```
Page not found
Exception information:

Message: Invalid controller specified (index)
Stack trace:

#0 D:\web\www\zf_hemr\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954):     Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http),     Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 D:\web\www\zf_hemr\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 D:\web\www\zf_hemr\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#3 D:\web\www\zf_hemr\public\index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}  

Request Parameters:

array (
  'module' => 'Admin',
  'controller' => 'index',
  'action' => 'index',
)
```

Can you please let me know where I went wrong?

Comment: Could you please add your project directory structure ?

Comment: sure.
https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=42249D719A3AB756&id=42249D719A3AB756!302
please see the above url to view the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to add `/modules`to your paths:

```
$front->setControllerDirectory(array(
                              'default' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default/controllers',
                              'Admin'   => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/Admin/controllers'
                              ));
```

However, you shouldn't have to do this, the right way to do it to me is to add these lines in your configuration.ini file:

```
resources.modules[] =
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.prefixDefaultModule = false
```

The first line **enables the resource plugin** `Zend_Application_Resource_Modules` that is going to take care of everything for you.

Comment: I have added the fontController. the application.ini is as follows:

Please look the url to view the application.ini and bootstrap.php file.

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=42249D719A3AB756&id=42249D719A3AB756!116

Comment: Add in your application.ini what I wrote just above.

Comment: I had added those lines. still I am not getting the module loaded in browser.

Comment: I have fixed this. the problem was i was not added controller index for admin module. Thanks for your support